# how can I run a group by query on a jsonb column with a gin index in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, group-by, jsonb

I have a table with a column named data that is formatted as jsonb.
I created a gin index on this column.

I would like to make postgres use the gin index when executing a group by clause.
What is the proper syntax for this query?
Here is an example entry from the data column

```
{"firstname": "Bob", "lastname": "Smith", "home_zip": "11234"}
```

I have tried this, but it postgres does not use the gin index when I run this query.

```
explain analyze select data#>'{home_zip}',count(*) from contacts group by data#>'{home_zip}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gin indexes do not support `can_order`, so can't be used to accelerate a group by (other than by accelerating the WHERE clause which feeds the GROUP BY).

You could accelerate this with an expression index through:

```
create index on contacts using btree ((data #> '{home_zip}'))
```